# Method getRowCount() return error when tring to sort Jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, abstracttablemodel, rowsorter

I'm novice in java swing and please help me with this.
I have a simple app that receives data from `2 JTextfileds` (name and occupation) and introduce them in a `JTable` after a button is pressed. The data are stored in a `List<Person>` where `Person(String name, String occupation)`.
The app works fine till I'm tring to sort the table using `TableRowSorter`.
I'll give you only the `TablePanel` and `PersonTableModel` code .

**TablePanel class**

```
import model.Person;

public class TablePanel extends JPanel {

    private JTable table;
    private PersonTableModel tablemodel;
    private TableListener tableListener;
    private RowSorter<PersonTableModel> sorter;

    public TablePanel(){
        tablemodel = new PersonTableModel();
        table = new JTable(tablemodel);


        //addSorter(); --- > comment this for you to see the problem


        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new JScrollPane(table),BorderLayout.CENTER);


    }

    private void addSorter() {
        if (tablemodel.getRowCount() != 0){
        sorter = new TableRowSorter<PersonTableModel>(tablemodel);
        table.setRowSorter(sorter);
        refresh();
        }
    }

    public void setData(List<Person> db){
        tablemodel.setData(db);
    }

    public void refresh(){
        tablemodel.fireTableDataChanged();
    }

    public void addTableListener(TableListener tableListener) {
        this.tableListener = tableListener;

    }
}
```

---

**PersonTableModel class**

```
public class PersonTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private List<Person> db = null;

    private String[] colNames = { "Id", "Name", "Occupation" };

    public void setData(List<Person> db) {
        this.db = db;
    }

    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return colNames[column];
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
        return db.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        Person person = db.get(rowIndex);

        switch (columnIndex) {
        case 0:
            return person.getId();
        case 1:
            return person.getName();
        case 2:
            return person.getOccupation();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Why I receive `NullPointerException` in method `getRowCount()` in `PersonTableModel` if I activate the method `addSorter()` ?

Comment: you have initialized `db` to null so before `getRowCount()` you have to call `setData()` and initialize it otherwilse you will get NUllPointer on `db.size()`

Comment: it doesn't work if i let it just "List<Person> db;"

Comment: You never called `setData(...)` on your `PersonTableModel`, hence the `NullPointerException`

Comment: change the line `private List<Person> db = null;` to `private List<Person> db=new ArrayList<Person>();`

Comment: Thanks singhakash ! it works fine now :D